# How might I create one UITableView with two data sources

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource

I have a UIViewController with one UITableView. But that tableView has two data sources. Basically a UIButton would decide which data source is active. How might I do that? there is no such method as

```
 [self.tableView reloadData:myDataSourceArray];
```

Which would help a great deal towards discriminating which data source to use and which UITableViewCell extension to use. So how might I go about this?

I say button to keep it simple, but in reality, dataSource_1 is preloaded from server while dataSource_2 is loaded by a UISearchBar.

Comment: Just do it.  Inside your delegate/dataSource examine a bool value which decides which array to use.  Do `reloadData` when you switch.  Or have a pointer that's set to one or the other, and, similarly do `reloadData` when you change the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a mutable array, say, `objectsToDisplayArray` and then on button click, assign which source you want then just call `reloadData`. If you want to change the source just remove all objects from objectsToDisplayArray, add the new data, then reload again.

Comment: It is more efficient to simply have a single property that refers to the active array and assign it as required - there is no reason to keep rebuilding the array

Comment: Yeah, constantly reloading a mutable array when you switch back and forth is a bit crazy.  You should somehow select between two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a BOOL to track which data source is active. This is necessary because you are also using two different extended classes of UITableViewCell. Say

```
BOOL dataSourceOneIsActive;
```

When you do `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `numberOfRowsInSection` you can check

```
if(dataSourceOneIsActive)
```

to determine which count and which cell and data source to use.

On the other hand, if you use the NSMutableArray idea, then you will have your work cut out for you when it comes time to decide which cell type to use.