# get value from cell then display details in other table view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I need when selecting a cell in table view to be able display its details in other table view in the same ViewController.

I just need any reference to start from. Most of the tutorials tells how to display data in other ViewController through segues. This is not my case. I need to display the details in the Same ViewController.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091494/how-might-i-create-one-uitableview-with-two-data-sources

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may helps you...

```
NSString *ClickedGroupId, *ClickedGroupName;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *labelName = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    ClickedGroupName= labelName.text;

    UILabel *labelId = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    ClickedGroupId= labelId.text;
}
```

**OR**

Get Index of seleted row and Select Value from your Array